# PowerShell Computer StartUp-Script - Switch user-context?

Tags: powershell

Through Microsoft Group Policy I did define to run a Powershell-Script on Computer Start-Up. Also I have the requirement to run a Powershell-Script as Scheduled Task without saving credentials. 
On both scenarios I have the same problem ...

I want to run a Citrix Powershell-Command (PSSnapIn) like:

```
Set-BrokerMachine -MachineName "domain.local\$env:COMPUTERNAME" -AdminAddress "RemoteServer.domain.local" -InMaintenanceMode $True
```

*Manual:* https://citrix.github.io/delivery-controller-sdk/Broker/Set-BrokerMachine/

Of course only users who have the permission could run those Citrix-commands. I would be able to give a domain-user the permission to run the command "Set-BrokerMachine", but in the mentioned scenarios the PowerShell-scripts run in context of the **system-user**.

I did simulate the system-user by PSExec:
[Error running as System-User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7byt.png)

My scripts do other things of course and I want to keep them running as System-User, but now I am looking for a **clean solution** to get those Citrix-commands running.

If possible, I don't want to save credentials in my scripts.

**EDIT #1:**

I would be able to workaround with the following code:

```
$Username = "MySpecialUser"
$Password = 'MyPassword'

$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Username, $SecurePassword

$Result = Invoke-Command -Session ( New-PSSession -ComputerName "RemoteServer.domain.local" -Credential $Credential ) -ScriptBlock {  

     Add-PSSnapin Citrix*
     Set-BrokerMachine -MachineName "domain.local\$args" -InMaintenanceMode $True

} -ArgumentList $env:COMPUTERNAME -HideComputerName

Remove-PSSession -InstanceId $Result.RunspaceId
```

I don't like this because:

- The code has to contain credentials (ofc I could encrypt it ...)
- I have to create a permission-system for this special user in Citrix
- I have to put the special-user into a local-group on every server, to allow the remote-administration (security-risk)
- I don't like to use PSSession
- ...

Is there a better/cleaner solution? Any ideas?

Comment: PowerShell is always ran in the context of the user who started it. You cannot use PowerShell to run code in the context as the logged on user. It's a Windows security boundary. This is why you'd use PSExec. Based on some of what you are after. IMHO, look to PowerShell JEA. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/jea/overview